How to make the image responsive gradually/smoothly (Reduce width first, then height)
I have an image that I want to be seen well in responsive mode, unfortunately, due to its large width, its height is too small on the phone!
There is a way that we can set an average height so that the height is not reduced too much, BUT its not an accurate method:
object-fit: cover;
min-height: 250px;

So the idea that came to my mind is to set a width range. and Reduce the width first, then the height.
Is this possible?:
whenever the browser was zooming out and wanted to reduce the height of the image, it should first reduce the width of the image (cover - zoom). gradually/smoothly up to the specified range (10% from the right and left) Then reduce the height while maintaining the reduced dimensions.
my code:


.ihero img {
width: 100%;
}
<a class="ihero" href="https://example.com/">
<img src="https://i.sstatic.net/fzY3Uxj6.jpg">
</a>




I couldn't understand the expected behavior, you mean when zooming using the mouse scroll on Ctrl +? You want to zoom only a part of the image?

Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Are you saying that it is essential that the middle 80% of the image be in view but that on wide enough viewports (“wide enough” to be defined)=the whole image should show?

@AHaworth Yes that's it, the browser should be able to remove 10% of each side of the image if needed

You can get some rather odd effects - if we gradually reduce the width of the viewport and the system jumps from showing 100% of the width to 80% then the area covered by the image actually gets bigger as the viewport gets smaller. This can't be what's required! Please could you explain what 'if needed' means in your comment.

@AHaworth If needed, it means that the width of the browser is reduced and thus the height of the image is reduced.
All I need is: when the browser wants to reduce the height of the image, first reduce its width by 10% (zoom).

“First reducing the width”will increase the height (assuming the image is to fill the viewport width). That is what I am not understanding.

Yes, you can achieve what you want to achieve, but you do need media queries to implement different styling at different viewport widths.
Your source image is 2560x600 pixels in size, but I’m assuming that you want to treat it as a @2x image, so in terms of CSS pixels we consider it to be 1280x300. With 10% cropped off each side, the image would be 2048x600, or 1024x300 in CSS pixels.

The overall strategy is to wrap the image in a container, constrain the container in various ways, set the image to fill the container and set object-fit: cover so that it will crop automatically.
At widths below 1024 pixels we constrain the container’s aspect-ratio to 1024/300. 20% of the image width is cropped, 10% from each side.
At widths between 1024 and 1280 pixels we constrain the container’s height to 300 and unconstrain the aspect-ratio. The crop varies smoothly from 20% at 1024 pixels to 0% at 1280 pixels.
At widths above 1280 pixels, both height and aspect-ratio can both be auto (or initial). The image is not cropped.

A snippet to demonstrate. After running it, make sure to use the full page link to test the responsive behaviour.


body {
  margin: 0;
}

a.ihero {
  aspect-ratio: 1024/300;
  border: 2px solid red;
  display: block;
}

@media (min-width: 1024px) {
  a.ihero {
    aspect-ratio: initial;
    height: 300px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1280px) {
  a.ihero {
    height: auto;
  }
}

a.ihero img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  display: block;
}
<a class="ihero" href="https://example.com/">
  <img src="https://i.sstatic.net/fzY3Uxj6.jpg">
</a>



After running this snippet, make sure to use the full page link to test the responsive behaviour.

Thanks, this is a better way and the best way I know right now, but I feel the way I said is much more responsive.
Can't we do that? Without using media query?

My interpretation of your desired result is that (a) if the viewport is wider than the image then the image should be stretched to fit the viewport while keeping its natural aspect ratio, (b) as the viewport shrinks to less than 100% of the intrinsic image width, you want the height to remain constant and the image to be cropped at the sides, then (c) once the viewport shrinks below 80% of the image width,  you want to retain that cropped aspect ratio from that point on? And during part (b) you want the crop to change gradually/smoothly during that phase, from 0% to 10% on each side?

Yes exactly, all I want is: whenever the browser was zooming out and wanted to reduce the height of the image, it should first reduce the width of the image (cover - zoom). gradually/smoothly up to the specified range (10% from the right and left)
Then reduce the height while maintaining the reduced dimensions.

I have updated my answer to better address your requirements. Can I suggest that you also edit your question to better explain your requirements? Stack Overflow is for posterity, you see, so we want this thread to be as clear as possible for people who might view it later.

Thanks bro, you are the best, I want to be you.
And I just want to know, can't we do this without @media?

I can’t think of a way to do it without @media queries, and why would you want to avoid using them, anyway? You only need to perform this trick for a single image on your website, right? Or were you hoping to use it for multiple images with different dimensions ... because if so, you're potentially going to need specific style rules for each image ... which is totally fine, it's just work.

width: calc(100vw - 10%);
height: auto;

You can also use transform: scaleX(0.9) or scale(0.9) as a temporary measure. Or use JS if nothing works in worst case.
